# Can't figure out a repeating rows/items issue with react-virtualized List

Tags: javascript, react-virtualized

I'm stuck on what might be a simple row and items rendering question with react-virtualized. I'm trying to render maybe 2000 cards in a big list. I'm able to get the items to render ok, but they render as separate rows with repeating items vs. a bunch of cards wrapping on rows flex-box style.

I can't tell if I have an odd closures problem or really what I need to do to not have the items repeat. Below is my code with comments (pics below that). Would love if someone could read my render function and suggest what I might be doing wrong.

```
<AutoSizer>
   {({ height, width }) => {
            const itemsPerRow = Math.floor(width / ITEM_SIZE);
            const rowCount = Math.ceil(this.props.videos.length / itemsPerRow);

            return (
              <List
                className="List"
                width={width}
                height={height}
                rowCount={rowCount}
                rowHeight={ITEM_SIZE}
                rowRenderer={({ index, key, style }) => {
                  const items = [];
                  const video = this.props.videos[index];

                  const fromIndex = index * itemsPerRow;
                  const toIndex = Math.min(
                    fromIndex + itemsPerRow,
                    this.props.videos.length
                  );

                  for (let i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
                    items.push(
                      <div className="Item" key={i}>
                        <ProductCard video={video} />
                      </div>
                    );
                  }

                  return (
                    <div className="Row" key={key} style={style}>
                      {items}
                    </div>
                  );
                }}
              />
            );
          }}
        </AutoSizer>
```

This is what shows up:
[image]

When I change the for loop to this:

```
for (let i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
                    items.push(
                      <div className="Item" key={i}>

                            Item {i}
                      </div>
                    );
                  }
```

It shows this:
[image]

I've read up again on closures and var vs. let loops. I just can't quite figure out what's missing here and why it works differently between the two examples. Thx for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just not selecting the videos. In a line `const video = this.props.videos[index];` You have selected the video and the same video is rendered through the row. Move the line inside the loop

Comment: Hmm..this didn't do it either:  for (let i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
                    let video = this.props.videos[index];
                    items.push(
                      <div className="Item" key={i}>
                        <ProductCard video={video} />

                      </div>
                    );
                  }

Comment: No try ` for (let i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) { let video = this.props.videos[i]; items.push( <div className="Item" key={i}> <ProductCard video={video} /> </div> ); }`